# Prettifying Code in Documents

Tags: macos, coding-style

I noticed on many websites and blogs they use some sort of library to format how their code looks with syntax-highlighting and line numbers. I was wondering if this effect is achievable in a Word Document or Mac OSX's Page application through some sort of plugin, script, or program? Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain why you down-voted the question?

Comment: I didn't down-vote but I'm guessing it's because the question is arguably not about programming *per se*. I wouldn't worry about it though = there are no close votes and you have at least one good answer already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People usually use a library like [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) (in Javascript, client-side) or [Pygments](http://pygments.org/) (in Python, server-side) to do the syntax highlighting.

If you are using Xcode, you can simply copy source code from the Xcode editor and paste it into your Word document.  The copy/paste operation will preserve the highlighting.  I suspect Pages will also keep the highlighting but I don't have a copy to test with.